# Given a permutation of 0..N-1, determine the index of that permutation in the lexicographic ordering of all permutations of 0..N-1, in linear time

Tags: permutations

There are various $\mathcal O(n \log n)$ or worse solutions, but I'm looking for one that runs in $\mathcal O(n)$, or a proof that none exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 2007 paper [Linear-time ranking of permutations](http://mj.ucw.cz/papers/rank.ps) gives a linear time ranking algorithm for the lexicographic order, assuming arithmetic on numbers of length $O(n\log n)$ takes constant time.

---

The 2001 paper [Ranking and unranking permutations in linear time](http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~ruskey/Publications/RankPerm/MyrvoldRuskey.pdf) presents a linear time ranking algorithm not requiring fast arithmetic on large numbers, but not for the lexicographic order. Regarding the latter, it states

> The whole problem of ranking permutations in lexicographic order seems inextricably intertwined with
>   the problem of computing the number of inversions
>   in a permutation, and it seems that a major breakthrough will be required to do that computation in linear time, if indeed it it possible at all.

On the other hand, it does mention an $O(n\log n/\log\log n)$ algorithm for ranking permutations in lexicographic order due to Dietz.

Answer (score 0):

Already [given answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/30276/17369) being good i wil add another (more recent) reference here:

[A New Method for Generating Permutations in
Lexicographic Order, by TING KUO (2009)](http://journal.dyu.edu.tw/dyujo/document/setjournal/s05-4-21-29.pdf)

proposes a method to generate, rank and unrank permutations in lexicographic order, plus a few new features like generate a permutation which is a given distance away from another permutation.

Complexity is again of the $O(nlgn)$ order

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.  The question says the OP already knows of $O(n \lg n)$ time algorithms, and is asking about $O(n)$ algorithms.  So, mentioning an $O(n \lg n)$ time algorithm is not answering the question.

Comment: @D.W., the answer exactly answers your comment. it is added as extra (and newer) reference. Plus the already upvoted answer also gives O(nlgn) solution for *lexicographic* ordering. there is no known algorithm for linear time lexicographic ordering (at least up to now). So the OP can have access to approximations anmd newer apporoaches, hopefully jimself may develop such an algorithm. Kindly remove the downvote please

Comment: I still don't see how it answers my comment.  Assume the other answer didn't exist (as it is irrelevant for these purposes).  How does your answer answer the question that was asked?  Take a look at the question again, and then your answer.  The question specifically says it does not want an $O(n \lg n)$ time algorithm (the author already knows of $O(n \lg n)$ time algorithms), so how does telling the OP about an $O(n \lg n)$ time algorithm answer the question?

Comment: @D.W., too bad, it seems your reputation is wasted on you, already answered, in any case let OP dcide. Again a similar anser has been given and is upvoted several times. There is **no** known algorithm for linear time lexicographic ordering. These are approximations (under certain conditions) which the OP may use or even help her derive her own algorithm. This is science after all even good approximations can be very helpful and references to these solutions. i hope you grant me that right

Comment: Stating that "There is no known linear time algorithm" would be an answer... but that's not present anywhere in your answer.  One can only judge your answer based on what is written in it.  (That said, I do recognize that that claim is already made in Yuval's answer, so it's not clear that it would contribute a lot to add another re-statement of that.)

Comment: I know you're only trying to help; I appreciate that. It sounds like you feel slighted -- I'm sorry to hear that.  But, on this site we expect the answer box to be used to answer the question that was asked, and we do expect and encourage everyone to vote, not just the OP.  This is a community standard, not my personal invention.  Also, I encourage you to avoid personal attacks and stick to the merits of the question/answer. "Your rep is wasted on you" could be viewed as an inappropriate personal attack.