# nth Permutation generator

Tags: algorithms, permutations

I'm just trying to write a little algorithm. I've got nine objects, so there's 9! permutations. My question is, is there a way of turning a number from 1 to 9! into a permutation?

for example, f(1)=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], f(2)=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,8] or something similar.

Each number should have a unique ordering, and vice versa.

I know it's possible to write out everything into an array, but that's very memory taxing. Is there a simpler way of doing it?

Comment: This is called _permutation unranking_. See this [Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system#Permutations) for an approach (see in particular the example for the 2982nd permutation of {0..6}). Essentially, divide your number by 8! to get the first digit. Then remove that digit from the set and proceed in similar fashion for the remaining 8 digits.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [factorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system).

See also https://oeis.org/wiki/Ranking_and_unranking_functions, [Given a permutation of 0..N-1, determine the index of that permutation in the lexicographic ordering of all permutations of 0..N-1, in linear time](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/30274/755) for more background.